# DNS MX forward one mailbox of a domain

Tags: dns, mx

I wanna know if exists a way to forward one mailbox with DNS MX entries ?, maybe with CNAME or other things. I want use for a particular mailbox a new mail services and for others mailboxes using the standard pop3 mail service of the original server.

It is a way to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

> I wanna know if exists a way to forward one mailbox with DNS MX
>   entries ?

No, and can't exist with MX. If you want forward one mailbox into *another mailbox on another host*, you **must**

- accept mail on domain-MX
- forward it (with *a lot of possible ways* in MTA) to final destination